# Get Touch Coordinates Relative To A Screen

Tags: coordinates, touch, screen

I have an image I am displaying to a user in my android application.

I want to be able to tell where the user 'touch' the image, relative to other users phones (screen size, reolutuion, density). In other words, I want to know the same location of the touch in the image/layout for every user on every phone.

I can easily get the screen coordinates by implementing an OnTouchListener.

How to make the formula?

I get the screen coordinates by implementing an OnTouchListener & user screen size and try to make a type of scale. It worked almost right, but there is a slight difference (especially in the -X).

```
float xRate = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
float yRate = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

xRate = 1800 / xRate;
yRate = 4000 / yRate;

 frame1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    textX.setText("X: " + event.getX() * xRate);                    
                    textY.setText("Y: " + event.getY() * yRate);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Thanks guys..